# Getting Hours from Libreoffice Calc

Tags: time, libreoffice-calc

well , I start using libre office calc, and I'm getting some troubles in order to manage some data hours.

So I have 3 times

like this on on [HH]:MM:SS

```
[A]       [B]       [C]  
01:12:11  28:58:40   00:10:09
```

so I wanna sum all of this no problem got this:

```
[D]
=SUM(A:C)  -- > 30:21:0
```

Until here , everything Ok, but I wanna take hours, mins and secs from that cell
so

```
=TIME(HOUR(D)) -- > and got 6
```

I try any other cell format didn't work, try changing  the cell format of A,B,C and still didn't work so 
Can someone help me please with this trouble

***edit:***
I wanna use the Hours , the true hours , the 30 hours to SUM with another hours that's why I wanna get the hours

***edit2:***

Example of what I want like this then

```
=SUM(HOUR(D*60)+MINUTES(D)+SECONDS(D/60)

and when you wanna get the real hours that is 30 , it will return you only 6
```

Comment: Be sure to search online for answers before asking a question. I entered "libreoffice calc more than 24 hours" into google and it found many good answers.

Comment: Sorry, but a good example would show the input and desired output, not only a formula that doesn't do what you want. I have no idea why you are trying to add hours and minutes together. 30 hours plus 21 minutes = 51, but that doesn't have any meaning. My answer already shows how to get the result of 30 hours, which is what you want according to the question.

Comment: After spending more time on this site, you will learn better how to ask and answer questions. It takes practice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 6 because 30 hours is one day and 6 hours. In order to show the value as 30 hours, enter `=D1`, then go to *Format -> Cells* and change the format to `[HH]`.

FAQ: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Formatting/Is_there_a_way_to_add_times_that_total_greater_than_24_hrs%3F

Also a note from https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/213897/how-to-show-more-than-24-hours-in-time-format-cells/:

> The square brackets tell the formatting routine not to apply the maximum cut needed for TOD.

Comment: already did but as I said previously I wanna compute , sum, etc the true hours :/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "true hours." As you said in the question, getting the sum is not a problem. Please edit the question to give a reproducible example and tell specifically what are the desired results.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good to explain sometimes sorry about it and thanks for your help & feedback

Comment: Just to be clear, there are two factors which affect how a cell or text is displayed: the actual cell value and the text format. If the time calculations are done correctly, then the deciding factor is the format. As @JimK stated, for amount of hours above 24, the correct format is "[HH]". So if we have a duration of 30:12 (30 hours and 12 minutes) in a cell D, and set the cell format to "[HH]", then the displayed value will be "30". The same effect can be achieved using the TEXT function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you specifically want to get hours, over 23.

To do that, I've chose a number format instead of time format and multiplied it by 24 (number format seem to show "per day" value, so `<value>*24`)